# Gulp компиляция scss при перезагрузке страницы

Tags: gulp, scss

Что нужно сделать чтобы происходила компиляция scss при перезагрузке страницы вот код:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('sass', function(){
    gulp.src('./project/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./project'))

});
gulp.task('sass:watch', function(){
    gulp.watch('./project/**/*.scss', ['sass']);
});
```

Comment: добавьте `.pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}));` (ну и соответственно нужен бс) к таску sass. Только компиляция будет происходить сначала, а потом уже перезагружаться страница, а не наоборот

Comment: Не работает, когда запускаю index.html ничего не работает

Comment: может нужно как-то связать с этим файлом